# How can I collapse an already expanded expandable row in an angular mat table?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have been trying to figure out how to collapse an expanded row when I click it on in angular. I have a page which has been written in a similar manner to this:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ygdrrokyvkv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html (this is from the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples )

Basically this allows you to expand a row and have any other rows that are expanded, to collapse. I want to be able to collapse the existing expanded row without expanding any others.

I was trying to mess around with the line:

```
<div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
```

to a nested if, something like:

```
 <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? element == expandedElement ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
```

which obviously doesn't work. I'm not very well-versed in HTML/Angular/(webby-stuff) so I wasn't sure what to google to find the correct syntax for this. What do you call something like [@detailExpand] ? A class method? A html method?
Thanks

Comment: `[@detailExpand]` refers to an animation defined in the component's typescript.

Comment: Hi @Faisal. Thanks for responding. Yes, I knew it pointed at that but i meant what is that actually called? Does it have a specific name? Like a class method? or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the click handler like so:

```
(click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"
```

This will ensure that, if you're clicking on the already expanded element, it will make `expandedElement` null, so no items become expanded

**[Here is a fork of the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4vrp4?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your help!